# Is it safe to dd a partition and restore it into a lvm volume?

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm trying to port my system from a simple partition to a LVM partition. To do so, I plan to `dd` my old partition to an external drive, create a LVM and volumes on the internal disk, and then restore the image onto one of the volumes.

Is this possible?

Comment: Be sure to back up your data beforehand regardless.

Comment: For your data? Yes. For bootable disk? Yes, but you will have to tweak the kernel command line (grub2 config) and may be recreate initramdisk.

Comment: @Martian, What if I don't touch my /boot (which is on another partition)? So that's safe then?